# Unable to implement InterstitialAdListener from MoPub

Tags: java, android, mopub

Per MoPub's [documentation](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Interstitial-Integration), my Activity is supposed to implement the interstitial ad listener, but I can't get it to work. MoPub's [interstitial demo](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/mopub-sample/src/main/java/com/mopub/simpleadsdemo/InterstitialDetailFragment.java) says it should look like this:

```
public class InterstitialDetailFragment extends Fragment implements InterstitialAdListener {
```

Mine looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements InterstitialAdListener {
```

(My app only has MainActivity and App classes)

But I get an error:

> Error:(70, 8) error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not
>   override abstract method onInterstitialDismissed(MoPubInterstitial) in
>   InterstitialAdListener

And Android Studio's recommendation is:

> Class 'MainActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement
>   abstract method 'onInterstitialDismissed(MoPubInterstitial)' in
>   'InterstitialAdListener'

What am I missing here?

Comment: An interface is a contract, you have to implement the methods it dictates. In this instance you have to implement the `onInterstitialDismissed(MoPubInterstitial)` method in your `MainActivity` class. Look at the last `@Override` method in the demo, that seems to be the one your missing, unless you left out all the other overridden methods in which case you'll have more errors.

Comment: Very well explained. This resolved the problem, although I feel quite foolish.